# HA - Heartbeat / Pacemaker - CentOS - Manual Symlinks

Tags: centos, high-availability, heartbeat

I have a MySQL Master <> Master pair setup for HA. I would like to setup automatic failover not just if the node hosting the current write mysql instance goes down, but also if the mysql instance itself becomes non-responsive.

In setting up heartbeat on CentOS 6.5 and trying to start the service with `pacemaker on`, I keep getting the following:

```
heartbeat[3285]: 2014/08/21_04:40:20 ERROR: Client child command [/usr/lib64/heartbeat/cib] is not executable
heartbeat[3285]: 2014/08/21_04:40:20 ERROR: Directive failfast  hacluster /usr/lib64/heartbeat/cib failed
heartbeat[3285]: 2014/08/21_04:40:20 ERROR: Client child command [/usr/lib64/heartbeat/stonithd] is not executable
heartbeat[3285]: 2014/08/21_04:40:20 ERROR: Directive respawn root /usr/lib64/heartbeat/stonithd failed
heartbeat[3285]: 2014/08/21_04:40:20 ERROR: Client child command [/usr/lib64/heartbeat/attrd] is not executable
heartbeat[3285]: 2014/08/21_04:40:20 ERROR: Directive respawn  hacluster /usr/lib64/heartbeat/attrd failed
heartbeat[3285]: 2014/08/21_04:40:20 ERROR: Client child command [/usr/lib64/heartbeat/crmd] is not executable
heartbeat[3285]: 2014/08/21_04:40:20 ERROR: Directive failfast  hacluster /usr/lib64/heartbeat/crmd failed
```

I did some digging around on the interwebs and a few posts said I had to manually symlink the files, is this true? Why wouldn't the package install do this automatically? Doesn't make sense that I would have to manually make these symlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found heartbeat to be a PITA to configure and implement on CentOS 6.5, as you can see from the question. This was the first package where I had to manually symlink etc., so rather than do the manual work, I did some more research and found keepalived, which works well, especially in an environment where only unicast is supported (cloud vps).

If you are looking for heartbeat functionality on a centos system, I suggest you read up on keepalived instead.